# Bluetooth Low Energy List

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

what is Bluetooth low energy in android.I know how to connect two devices using Bluetooth. But i don't  know How to connect two android device using Bluetooth low energy.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html

Comment: yes i read documentation.and download source code from here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt/

Comment: but could not get BLE device list

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get a list of Bluetooth LE (Low Energy) devices. You need to use the Bluetooth LE scanning API's.

If you are supporting API's lower than 21 (above 18, though) you should use the [startLeScan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#startLeScan(android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback))() to discover LE devices. When on API level 21 and above, you get access to a more robust and powerful scanning API that allows you to customize the devices returned back based on Services available, device name, MAC address and such. Instead of calling startLeScan on the [BluetoothAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html), you'd call [startScan](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html#startScan(java.util.List%3Candroid.bluetooth.le.ScanFilter%3E,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanSettings,%20android.bluetooth.le.ScanCallback))() on a [BluetoothLeScanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeScanner.html) object that you'd get from BluetoothAdapter via a call to [getBluetoothLeScanner](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothAdapter.html#getBluetoothLeScanner())().

When using either API, you must have [BLUETOOTH_ADMIN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BLUETOOTH_ADMIN) permission. You most also hold the at least one of the following location permissions, [ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) or [ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) when running on API 21 and above.

To connect to an LE device you simply need to call [connectGatt](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#connectGatt(android.content.Context,%20boolean,%20android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback))() on a LE [BluetoothDevice](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html). You can check if a BluetoothDevice is an LE device by calling [getType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#getType)() which returns a int constant that represents one of the various bluetooth device types android supports.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect two device using bluetooth low energy then you need to make one device as a simulator same as BLE device, like your device one is advertising and In second device you need to scan that device and connect that device and now your both device is connected. you can send and receive data.
For Bluetooth advertising : 
refer this link : - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/BluetoothLeAdvertiser